# "Mesh -> Full" Disables MeshFunction in ParametricPlot3D

Tags: plotting, graphics3d, mesh, computational-geometry

Here's my code

```
a := -2
q := 1/Sqrt[Abs[a]]
r[u_] = Cosh[q*u]^-a
h[u_] = -(1/q) Integrate[Cosh[q*u]^(-a - 1), u]
m[u_, v_] := r[u] *Cos[v]
k[u_, v_] := r[u]* Sin[v]
FSurface[u_, v_] := {m[u, v], k[u, v], h[u]} 
GGP = ParametricPlot3D[FSurface[u, v], {u, -2 , 2 }, {v, 0, 2 \[Pi]}, 
  BoxRatios -> {3, 3, 3}, PlotPoints -> 50, MaxRecursion -> 0, 
  Mesh -> Full, MeshFunctions -> {#4 + #5 &, #4 - #5 &}, 
  Method -> "BoundaryOffset" -> False, PerformanceGoal -> "Quality"]
(*Delete triangles in the mesh*)
GGPT := DeleteCases[GGP, _Polygon, \[Infinity]]
DiscretizeGraphics[GGPT]
```

My goal is to plot the surface and then get different meshes of it. Here's the plot and mesh Mathematica generates.

[image: Mesh Along iso-parameter lines]

I would like a mesh on the surface that cuts this mesh diagonally. This mean we can just rotate the mesh by 45 degrees. When I do so using `MeshFunctions -> {#4 + #5 &, #4 - #5 &}`, I get the following:
[image: Desired Mesh but with weird behavior around 0, where lines don't meet]

The problem with this mesh is that the lines don't meet around 0. Using `Mesh -> 50` or any number doesn't fix it because the problem persists and it creates point that aren't vertices.

[image: ugly mesh]

This can be fixed using `Mesh -> All`. However, when I do so, `DiscretizeGraphics` doesn't work.

A method that I found that generates a good mesh is using `Mesh -> Full`. It creates a mesh where all the points are vertices as bellow.

[image: nice mesh where the only points are vertices]

Basically, I want to `DiscretizeGraphics` of a mesh which has points only on the vertices. I wish i can use `Mesh -> Full` and `MeshFunctions -> {#4 + #5 &, #4 - #5 &}` together and then discretized graphics but they seem to negate each other.

Thank you in advanced for your help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think it's easier just to program the mesh than to try to get complicated, sophisticated functions like `ParametricPlot3D` to do something simple.  The function `sleeveMesh3D` creates a 2D, right-triangular mesh of the domain $[0,1]^2$ and applies a function which should be periodic in the first coordinate with period $1$.

```
sleeveMesh3D // ClearAll;
sleeveMesh3D[f_, m_Integer, n_Integer] := 
  With[{pts = 
     f /@ Tuples@{Most@Subdivide[0, 1, m], Subdivide[0, 1, n]}},
   GraphicsComplex[
    pts,
    Table[
      Line[{
        (n + 1) Mod[i - 1, m] + j, 
        (n + 1) Mod[i, m] + j + 1}],
      {i, 0, m - 1}, {j, n}
      ] ~Join~
     Table[
      Line[{
        (n + 1) Mod[i, m] + j, 
        (n + 1) Mod[i, m] + j + 1}], 
      {i, 0, m - 1}, {j, 1, n}]
    ]
   ];
```

Example:

```
With[{i = 24, j = 20},
  Graphics3D[
   sleeveMesh3D[
    FSurface[
      Rescale[#[[2]], {0, 1}, {-2, 2}],
      Rescale[#[[1]] - #[[2]]*j/(2 i), (* rotate each layer *)
       {0, 1}, {0, 2 Pi}]
      ] &, i, j]]
  ] // DiscretizeGraphics
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! I never really created a mesh before. I will try to study sleeveMesh3D and figure out exactly what it does. My goal is to create a quad mesh along the asymptotic curves, in this case it's 45 degrees off the iso parameter lines(the ones Mathematica generates). I want to do other mesh parametrization as well. I assume I would only need to modify the rescaling part to change the directions right?

Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: @Mhajji You're welcome! If you replace the `GraphicsComplex[..]` with `GraphicsComplex[pts, Join[{Blue}, Table[Line[{(n + 1) Mod[i - 1, m] + j, (n + 1) Mod[i, m] + j + 1}], {i, 0, m - 1}, {j, n}], {Red}, Table[Line[{(n + 1) Mod[i, m] + j, (n + 1) Mod[i, m] + j + 1}], {i, 0, m - 1}, {j, 1, n}] ] ]` you can see what the two `Table` commands do. And `With[{i = 8, j = 5}, Graphics[sleeveMesh3D[Identity, i, j], PlotRange -> {{0, 1}, {0, 1}}, Frame -> True]]` shows what the domain looks like before mapping it onto the hyperboloid.